# Get Matches of lines

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is Example string that I have.

`143s: WHAT IS <span>THAT</span>? 144s: HEAR THAT? 152s: EVERYBODY, SHH. SHH. 156s: <span>STAY</span> UP THERE. 163s: [BOAT CREAKING] 165s: WHAT IS THAT? 167s: [SCREAMING] 191s: COME ON! 192s: OH, GOD! 193s: AAH! 249s: OK. WE'VE HAD SOME PROBLEMS 253s: AT THE FACILITY. 253s: WHAT WE'RE ATTEMPTING TO <span>ACHIEVE</span> 256s: HERE HAS <span>NEVER</span> BEEN DONE. 256s: WE'RE THIS CLOSE 259s: TO THE REACTIVATION 259s: OF A HUMAN BRAIN CELL. 260s: DOCTOR, THE 200 MILLION 264s: I'VE SUNK INTO THIS COMPANY 264s: IS DUE IN GREAT PART 266s: TO YOUR RESEARCH.`

Consider , string with `ns:` and text, after is, as a single line.

e.g. `259s: OF A HUMAN BRAIN CELL.`

I need regular expression , which returns me lines having ,

```
Previous Line of Line having span tag if any + Line having span tag  + Next Line of having span tag if any
```

So above string should return me 3 matches.

```
1st : 143s: WHAT IS <span>THAT</span>? 144s: HEAR THAT?
2nd : 152s: EVERYBODY, SHH. SHH. 156s: <span>STAY</span> UP THERE. 163s: [BOAT CREAKING]
3rd : 253s: WHAT WE'RE ATTEMPTING TO <span>ACHIEVE</span> 256s: HERE HAS <span>NEVER</span> BEEN DONE
```

Comment: Could you try and explain the criteria you're using to split the lines? I've read, and re-read, your explanation but I'm afraid I really don't follow.

Comment: Could I suggest that, if this is 'urgent,' you try helping us, by answering the questions left in the previous comments? Currently, given your lack of response, I'm seriously considering closing as 'not a real question.' Please, help *us* to help *you*.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry , if you feel lack of response. but this is due to internet connection issues.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 , i need it in javascript. thanks

Comment: @DavidThomas, my line is starting from 'ns:' , where n is number between 0 to 3600. and the text after that. until next `ns:` do not encounter, i hope it is understandable now

Answer (score 1):

"*Previous line having…*" is a condition that would need [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is not supported by JS. However, the regex would have been overly complicated, so instead just parse it and loop through the lines checking for your matches.

```
var text = "…";

var lines = [],
    textparts = text.split(/(\d+s:)/);
for (var i=1; i<textparts.length; i+=2)
    lines[(i-1)/2] = {
        lineNumber: textparts[i].match(/\d+/)[0],
        text: textparts[i+1],
        hasSpan: /<span>/.test(textparts[i+1])
    };
var matchedlines = [];
for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
    if (lines[i-1] && lines[i-1].hasSpan && lines[i].hasSpan && …) // or whatever
         matchedlines.push(lines[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for your reply. I have tried to get just line having `</span>` using below regex. but i m not succeed to do that. can you help me please!!?
Regex : `\b(\d{1,4}s:(*.?))\b(?=</span>)`

Comment: thanks @Bergi, again for your updates. but we had tried this. we need it in regex

Comment: @meghana: What's wrong with this? Why does your client insist on regexes? They are the wrong tool for this (or I didn't understand your requirements too well)

Comment: we need to optimize the extent al a level we can

Comment: Optimize what, unreadability? :-) Complex regexes are much less performant than simple parsers